# Copy files with cp (unix) but skip files which can't copy

Tags: unix, copy, backup, cp

i have to backup exiting /dev/sdX but cp hangs on one file (/proc/kmsg). It can't skip it... Just hangs like it's copying a 34KB file.

So how can i skip this file?

Comment: There's no reason to back up _anything_ under /proc (or /sys): they're virtual filesystems, the kernel generates them.

Comment: Have you considered using `rsync -av` along with the `--exclude`? Backing up `/proc` is kind of pointless anyway.

Comment: Also copying a 34KB file should happen in the blink of an eye

Comment: THANX! I didn't know about rsync tool!

Answer (score 1):

You can copy files with Midnight Commander and then press skip button if you see that the file copy is stalled.

If you have just one file, it works perfectly. However, if there are too many files, it is hard to do manually. I wrote a [bash script](https://github.com/asapegin/timeout_folder_rescue) to deal with such situations.